# How to convert dataframe into numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

So I am currently making a neural network MLP (Multi-layer-Perceptron) on group classification on sea turtle speed between beach to sea on the seconds unit, and it looks somewhat like this.

[image]

Now on my Jupyter Notebook I type the following

```
data = pd.read_csv("SeaTurtles.csv")
data
```

It shows the data in dataframe

[image]

What I wanted to do is to separate these two groups which are group A for "Training" data and group B for "Testing" data. I wanted to convert the dataframe into a NumPy array so that it would make it easier for me to classify them into the SpeciesCode.
So I type in:

```
newdf=data.drop(['Group1','Group 2'], axis = 1)
newdf
```

[image]

I need to split it into two test group A and B so I typed in

```
groupA=newdf.loc[newdf['Test*'] == 'A']
groupB=newdf.loc[newdf['Test*'] == 'B']
```

[image]

Group B
[image]

What I did was to convert these into numpy array with .to_numpy()

```
groupA = groupA.to_numpy()
groupA
```

and it returns the "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
"
[image]

My question is did I do something wrong or is there another way for me to convert this dataframe into numpy array so that I can start training the data? Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the error message it already is a numpy array

Comment: numpy arrays can be filled with only one datatype, (their `dtype`). Your dataframes contain multiple different datatypes. (floats and strings).

Comment: Any chance you evaluated `groupA = groupA.to_numpy()` twice in a row? You're using the same variable name as input and output.

Comment: please print `type(groupA)`

Comment: Okay, should I separate them first previously? I tried doing the .drop() after grouping them according to A and B and it still would not drop.

Comment: Okay I will try that first.

Comment: It says numpy.ndarray when I print type(groupA)

Comment: it means that **groupA** already **numpy** array ․you do not need convert it to np.array

Comment: That has been very helpful. Is there another way for me to drop the Test* category  and species category since I already group them into different group represented by the variable groupA and groupB?

Answer (score -1):

Pandas dataframe is a two-dimensional data structure to store and retrieve data in rows and columns format.

You can convert pandas dataframe to numpy array using the `df.to_numpy()` method.

You can use the below code snippet to convert pandas dataframe into numpy array.

```
numpy_array = df.to_numpy()
print(type(numpy_array))
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Read question again. This is not the answer to his question!

Answer (score -2):

Just add [0] to groupA.groupA.to_numpy()

```
groupA = groupA[0].to_numpy()
groupA
```